# Position of "nicht" in a subordinate clause, where?

Tags: subordinate-clause, negation

Where should a "nicht" in a subordinate clause be positioned?

> - without *nicht*: "ich glaube, dass das gut ist"
> - with *nicht*: "ich glaube, dass das **nicht** gut ist"
>     or
> - with *nicht*: "ich glaube, dass das gut **nicht** ist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nicht** has to be placed in front of the item you want to negate, with the exception of a verb in second position. It's put at the end of the clause instead then.

> …, dass das gut ist.

In this subordinate clause, there are two items to negate.

> …, dass nicht **das** gut ist (, sondern etwas anderes).
>
> …, dass das nicht **gut ist** (, sondern schlecht ist).

I marked *gut ist* as the item to negate instead of *gut*, because it's the predicative use of the adjective *gut*.